# Syntax error in SAProuter script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I came across following script:

```
      #!/bin/sh
### Variables ###
porta="3299";
SECUDIR="/usr/sap/saprouter";
SNC_LIB="/usr/sap/saprouter/libsapcrypto.so";
DNAME="p:CN=server, OU=0001000000, OU=SAProuter, O=SAP, C=DE";
### Variables end ###

### Check if saprouter is already running:
pid1="'netstat -nlp | grep '0.0.0.0:"$porta"'.*saprouter' | sed -n 1p | awk '{print $7}' | cut -f1 -d "/" '";

if [ "$pid1" == "" ]

then # Not running.

  ### check if the port is free:
echo -e "\nChecking port…";
processo="'netstat -nlp | grep 0.0.0.0:"$porta" | sed -n 1p | awk '{print $7}' | cut -f1 -d "/"'";
sleep 2;

  # If port free:
if [ -f $processo ]
then
echo -e "\nStarting SAPRouter on port: " $porta;
sleep 2;
export SECUDIR=$SECUDIR
export SNC_LIB=$SNC_LIB

  /usr/sap/saprouter/./saprouter -r -R "$SECUDIR/saprouttab" -W 60000 -G "$SECUDIR/saprouterlog.txt" -S $porta -K "$DNAME" &

  pid="'netstat -nlp | grep '0.0.0.0:'"$porta"'.*saprouter' | sed -n 1p | awk '{print $7}' | cut -f1 -d "/" '";
echo -e "\n\nSAPRouter is running on PID: "$pid;
echo -e "\n";
exit;
# if the port isnot free.

  else
echo -e '——————————————————-\n';
echo -e ' It is not possible to start SAPRouter\n';
echo -e ' The PID: '$processo' is already using the port: ' $porta;
echo -e '——————————————————-\n';
fi

  ###################
else # Its already running.
echo -e "\nSAPRouter is already running";
pid="'ps -ef | grep saprouter | sed -n 1p | awk '{print $2}' '";
echo -e "\nPID: "$pid;
echo -e "\n";
sleep 2;
fi
```

I think there are several errors present. I found the code [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/03/29/script-to-start-saprouter-on-unix/): 
There is a comment fixing some errors but I do not think that all errors are fixed. I noticed the quotes `”`, which I replaced with `"`. But I am still getting this error:

```
run_router.sh: 12: [: 'netstat -nlp | grep '0.0.0.0:3299'.*saprouter' | sed -n 1p | awk '{print }' | cut -f1 -d / ': unexpected operator
-e 
SAPRouter is already running
-e 
PID: 'ps -ef | grep saprouter | sed -n 1p | awk '{print }' '
-e
```

Since I have no experience with scripts, I do not know what quoted string is unterminated, since there is a lot of quoted strings on this line:

```
pid1="'netstat -nlp | grep '0.0.0.0:"$porta"'.*saprouter' | sed -n 1p | awk '{print $7}' | cut -f1 -d "/" '";
```

Could you help me fix this script?

Thanks.

Comment: @steeldriver I did, still getting 'netstat -nlp | grep '0.0.0.0:3299'.*saprouter' | sed -n 1p |awk '{print }' | cut -f1 -d / ' : unexpected operator

Answer (score 2):

*The following attempts to address the syntax errors specifically. There may be other issues that make it fail to work the way you expect*: for example, the line

```
if [ -f $processo ]
```

tests whether a *regular file* exisits whose name is given by the contents of the `processo` variable - however `processo` appears likely to contain a numeric process ID (PID). Perhaps what the author intended was

```
if [ -n "$processo" ]
```

to test whether the variable is non-empty or (more likely, given the context)

```
if [ -z "$processo" ]
```

to test whether it is empty.

---

When you corrected the HTML formating of the downloaded script it looks like you replaced at least some of the smart quotes with the "wrong" ASCII characters - in particular

```
processo="'netstat -nlp | grep 0.0.0.0:"$porta" | sed -n 1p | awk '{print $7}' | cut -f1 -d "/"'";
```

and

```
  pid="'netstat -nlp | grep '0.0.0.0:'"$porta"'.*saprouter' | sed -n 1p | awk '{print $7}' | cut -f1 -d "/" '";
```

should have "backticks" (for command substitution) instead of regular straight single quotes

```
processo="`netstat -nlp | grep 0.0.0.0:"$porta" | sed -n 1p | awk '{print $7}' | cut -f1 -d "/"`";

  pid="`netstat -nlp | grep '0.0.0.0:'"$porta"'.*saprouter' | sed -n 1p | awk '{print $7}' | cut -f1 -d "/" `";
```

Better yet, change them to the more modern `$(...)` construct:

```
processo="$(netstat -nlp | grep 0.0.0.0:"$porta" | sed -n 1p | awk '{print $7}' | cut -f1 -d "/")";

  pid="$(netstat -nlp | grep '0.0.0.0:'"$porta"'.*saprouter' | sed -n 1p | awk '{print $7}' | cut -f1 -d "/" )";
```